# An MCQ involving Rayleigh - Ritz method for the functional $I(y) = \int_{0}^{1}(\frac{1}{2}(y^{'})^2 - y)dx$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> An MCQ involving Rayleigh - Ritz method for the functional $$I(y) = \int_{0}^{1}(\frac{1}{2}(y^{'})^2 - y)dx$$

Let $y_\text{app}$ be  polynomial approximation, involving only one coordinate function, for the functional
$$I(y) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2}(y^{'})^2 - y\right) \, dx ;\quad y(0) = 0,\ y(1) = 0$$
using the Rayleigh - Ritz method; here $y \in C^2[0, 1]$

If $y_e (x)$ is an exact extremizing function, then $y_e$ and $y_\text{app}$ are coincident at

1. $x = 0$ but not at remaining points in $[0, 1]$
2. $x = 1$ but not at remaining points in $[0, 1]$
3. $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, but not at other points in $[0, 1]$
4. all points in $x\in [0, 1]$

It can be shown that $y_e$ is quadratic by Euler Lagrange's method.

Somewhere I found a solution of this problem, there it was written that $y_{app}$ must be a quadratic  polynomial, and it coincides with $y_e$ at two points viz., 0 and 1, so it will coincide $y_e$ at all points. I could not understand that why $y_{app}$ must be a quadratic  polynomial? What is meant by an involvement of one coordinate function?

Please somebody tell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to find out $y_{app}$

take it of the form $ y= cx(1-x)$ i.e. a function vanishing on given boundary conditions. now calculate $y'$ and put it in the integral.

$I(y)=\frac{c^2-c}{6}$. Now by rayleigh Ritz find out $\frac{dI}{dc}$ and put it equal to $0$ to find out $c$. yow will get $y_{app}=\frac{x-x^2}{2}$. Further $y_e$ calculating by Euler Lagrange method comes out equal to $y_{app}$.

so d is answer.